# Can I use go on a shared web server to generate HTML?

Tags: go, hosting

Normally I use C# for everything, I can create a desktop application with C# and also place a lot of the same c# code in a dll on my shared hosted web server. This saves me a lot of coding time.

Is there any way to this with go?
e.g. place some kind of go dll on my hosted web server to generate HTML.

I am aware that go doesn't do dll's, I am also aware that creating a web server with go to listen to port 80 is straight forward. But this is not a solution for a shared web server.

This seems like a brilliant use for go and it surprises me that this might not be possible.

I should mention, it would be nice if the go code didn't have to restart with every http request.

This is how I do it with C#:
On the web server I add an aspx page like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MyDLL" Namespace="MyDLL" Assembly="MyDLL"%>
<MyDLL:Web Runat="Server"/>
```

It simply loads the C# dll which generates HTML based on the http request.

Comment: what do you mean by "hosted server"? You could theoretically run go as a CGI if you wanted.

Comment: I mean a shared web server that I pay a monthly fee for, and it hosts my websites. I upload files to it. Currently I have a windows server though I can change that. You might need to explain your CGI suggestion a bit more.

Comment: Does your host support (fast)cgi? http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi

Comment: Yes it does, though I don't really know what that is.

Comment: I think the best go equivalent for what you're doing is the Google App Engine.

Comment: App engine, might be a way to do this. I'll look into it more.

Comment: I posted how to use fastcgi but it'd probably more convenient to use google app engine or a server that lets you run your own executables and just use your Go app as standalone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to setup IIS to use fastcgi ([instructions](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/fastcgi)) then you can simply build a go web app like you normally would but instead of using http.ListenAndServe you use `fcgi.Serve`

[Example](http://play.golang.org/p/aGdJ5L0U7W):

```
func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "Hello, world of FCGI!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello/", hello)

    if err := fcgi.Serve(nil, nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("fcgi.Serve: ", err)
    }
}
```

But keep in mind that there can be multiple instances of the programming running / destroyed all the time, so any temp data (in-memory sessions, etc) should be stored on memcache or temp files on disk or a database.

Comment: This looks like the solution. Thanks I'll try it out.

Comment: Looks pretty complex though.